# JavaScript if/else conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to print the error message if the **minimum value > maximum value** for both horizontal and vertical directions for my multiplication table.

For example:
[image]

For some reason, my code only prints the error message if the *Row* values have to be swapped, it doesn't print the message for *Column* values.
Also, **I need a case if they both have to be swapped**, but when I add this condition nothing works(I left it commented out).

script.js:

```
 if(minCol>maxCol)
 {
   let temp = maxCol;
   maxCol = minCol;
   minCol = temp;
   error.textContent = "Minimum Column Value has been swapped with Maximum Column Value.";
   error.style.color = "red";
 }
 if(minRow>maxRow)
 {
   let temp = maxRow;
   maxRow = minRow;
   minRow = temp;
   error.textContent = "Minimum Row Value has been swapped with Maximum Row Value.";
   error.style.color = "red";
 }
 /*
 if(minCol>maxCol && minRow>maxRow)
 {
   error.textContent = "Minimum Column and Row Value has been swapped with Maximum Column and Row Value.";
   error.style.color = "red";
 }
 */
 else 
 {
   error.textContent = "";
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to _append_ to `error.textContent` instead of _replacing_ its value.  Start with `error.textContent = '';`, then do `error.textContent += 'your error';` whenever you need to show a message.  Then you can get rid of the `else` at the bottom.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thank you so much! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *replacing* `error.textContent` every time you hit one of your `if` conditions, meaning only error message can be set at a time.  Also, your `else` is deleting the message if `minRow > maxRow` is false, ignoring the `minCol > maxCol` condition.

Try setting `error.textContent = '';` at the beginning and then appending to the error message.

```
error.textContent = "";

if(minCol>maxCol)
{
   let temp = maxCol;
   maxCol = minCol;
   minCol = temp;
   error.textContent += "Minimum Column Value has been swapped with Maximum Column Value.";
   error.style.color = "red";
}

if(minRow>maxRow)
{
   let temp = maxRow;
   maxRow = minRow;
   minRow = temp;
   error.textContent += "Minimum Row Value has been swapped with Maximum Row Value.";
   error.style.color = "red";
}
```